# Custom Meta data in Aura Design File

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-metadata

Currently have an aura component where the object is hard coded in the cmp and design file.
I would like to use a cmt so that the object can

```
<design:component>
 <design:attribute name="title" label="Component Title" required="false" />
  <design:attribute
    name="lookupFielName"
    label="Lookup Field Name"
    required="false"
    default="Account"
  />
</design:component
```

> 

I am querying the cmt in a controller

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static List < File_Object__mdt > fetchFileObject() {
    return [SELECT File_Object__c FROM File_Object__mdt ];
}
```

When I add the cmt to the cmp attribute:

```
  <aura:attribute name="lookupFieldApiName" type="File_Object__mdt[]"  
  <aura:attribute
    name="title"
    type="String"
    default="Files available to share"
  />
```

I get an error:  The flexipage:availableForRecordHome interface doesn't support these attribute types in the design resource: file_object__mdt[].

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm):

> For Lightning page interfaces, the design resource supports only attributes of type Integer, String, or Boolean. To see which attribute types the lightning:availableForFlowScreens interface supports, go to [Which Custom Lightning Component Attribute Types Are Supported in Flows?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_tips_map.htm).

So, basically, you can't use whatever data type you'd like. Your attribute must be a String, Boolean, or Integer data type. You'll need a dedicated attribute for this purpose.

If you'd like to use those metadata values in the editor, you could use the datasource attribute:

```
<design:attribute name="property1" datasource="apex://MyCustomPickList"/>
```

Which requires a class:

```
global class MyCustomPickList extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList{
    
    global override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue(){
        VisualEditor.DataRow defaultValue = new VisualEditor.DataRow('red', 'RED');
        return defaultValue;
    }
    global override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
        VisualEditor.DataRow value1 = new VisualEditor.DataRow('red', 'RED');
        VisualEditor.DataRow value2 = new VisualEditor.DataRow('yellow', 'YELLOW');
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows  myValues = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        myValues.addRow(value1);
        myValues.addRow(value2);
        return myValues;
    }
}
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm#components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists).

Comment: thanks @sfdxfox.  I read this article:
https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/03/how-to-show-custom-metadatatype-records.html
Thought I could use the same approach.  Just trying not to hardcode the Object value but have it in a cmt record where each org can define what object to use. Thx

Comment: @Phuc Right, but you can't do this in the Lightning App Builder. You need to use an Apex class, as mentioned here.

Comment: @sfdxfox, to confirm, I need an apex class other than the controller I am using? 
<aura:component
  implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"
  controller="FileController"
> 
The FileController is where I am querying the mdt.  Thanks

Comment: @Phuc I haven't *tried* using the same controller for both, so I can't confirm that you "need" to have a separate class, but I wouldn't recommend using the same class for both.